# pytest will not run the test files in subdirectories

Tags: python, unit-testing, testing, command, pytest

I am new to pytest and trying to run a simple test to check if pytest works. I'm using windows 10, python 3.8.5 and pytest 6.0.1.

Here is my project directory:

```
projects
 └-tests    
    |-__init__.py   
    └-test_sample.py
```

Here is what I put in test_sample.py:

```py
def func(x):
    return x + 1

def test_answer():
    assert func(3) == 5
```

If I do the following:

```
> pytest 
the test run fine (1 failed in 0.004s)
> pytest tests/test_sample.py 
the test run fine (1 failed in 0.006s)
```

However, if I do this:

```
> pytest test_sample.py
```

It will return a message like this:

```
no test ran in 0.000s
ERROR: file not found: test_sample.py
```

I tried deleting `__init__.py` file but the result was still the same. Also, I have tried this on 2 different computers but nothing changed. In case the problem can't be solved, can I just ignore it and move on with the solutions I'm having?

Comment: You are running `pytest test_sample.py`, yet your `test_sample.py` is inside the `tests` folder. You should do `pytest ./tests/test_sample.py`.

Comment: Thanks for your help. May I ask you what the use of `__init__.py` in the `tests` folder is? I realize that nothing changed whenever I remove or added that file?

Comment: If it's an empty `__init__.py` file, then you don't need it, knowing that you're running python 3.8.5.

Comment: You can use search test by keyword:  pytest -k “test_sample”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "best practices" approach to configuring a project with pytest is using [a config file](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#initialization-determining-rootdir-and-configfile). The simplest solution is a `pytest.ini` that looks like this:

```py
# pytest.ini
[pytest]

testpaths = tests
```

This configures the [`testpaths`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/reference.html#confval-testpaths) relative to your [`rootdir`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir) (pytest will tell you what both paths are whenever you run it). This answers the specific problem you raised in your question.

```
C:\YourProject  <<-- Run pytest on this path and it will be considered your rootdir.
│
│ pytest.ini
│ your_module.py
│
├───tests       <<-- This is the directory you configured as testpaths in pytest.ini
│     __init__.py
│     test_sample.py
```

Your example was about running specific tests from the command line. The complete set of rules for [finding the `rootdir` from `args`](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/customize.html#finding-the-rootdir) is somewhat contrived.

You should notice that pytest currently supports [two possible layouts](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules) for your tests and modules. It's currently [strongly suggested by pytest documentation to use a `src` layout](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/goodpractices.html#choosing-a-test-layout-import-rules). Answering about the importance of using `__init__.py` depends on the former to an extent, however choosing a configuration file and layout still takes precedence over how you choose to use `__init__.py` to define your packages.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `tests/test_sample.py` with these commands below according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/how-to/usage.html#specifying-which-tests-to-run):

```
pytest
```

Or:

```
pytest tests
```

Or:

```
pytest tests/test_sample.py
```

Or:

```
pytest tests/test_sample.py::test_answer
```

In addition, you better put [pytest.ini](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.3.x/reference/customize.html#pytest-ini) to the root directory of `projects` folder as shown below:

```py
projects
 |-pytest.ini # Here
 └-tests    
    |-__init__.py   
    └-test_sample.py
```

Then, you better set `tests` to [testpaths](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths) in `pytest.ini` as shown below to run tests faster according to [the doc](https://docs.pytest.org/en/7.1.x/reference/reference.html#confval-testpaths):

```ini
# "pytest.ini"

[pytest]
testpaths = tests # Here
```